# How do you show that $\det(A)$ is the product of a linear form in $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and a linear form in $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Someone pointed out another solution on how to prove [Showing the determinant for a specific type of matrix is $\det(A) = (-1)^n 2^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{i-1} a_{i+1} \ldots a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79698/7980) and it involves a type of cofactor expansion theorem of a specific form.

Assuming some additional conditions on the ring and using the following formula

$\det(A)  = \det (\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} &  \ldots & a_{1n}   \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots &  a_{2n}  \\
. & . &  . & .   \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix} ) z - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{i + j} M_{ij}x_i y_i$

where

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} &  \ldots & a_{1n} & x_1  \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots &  a_{2n} & x_2 \\
. & . &  . & .  & . \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn} &  x_n \\
y_1 & y_2 & \ldots & y_n & z
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and $M_{ij}$ is the minor of order $n-1$.

Then if we assume all $a_{ij}$ are elements of a field and  $\det (\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} &  \ldots & a_{1n}   \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots &  a_{2n}  \\
. & . &  . & .   \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix} ) = 0 $ then

> How do you show that $\det(A)$ is the product of a linear form in $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and a linear form in $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$?

Comment: What is $z$? A field element? An indeterminant?

Comment: @BillCook It doesn't matter, the term with $z$ disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the determinant of the matrix $A$ is 0, there is one row of $A$ that can be expressed as linear combination of the other rows, $row_k=\sum_{l\neq k}c_lrow_l$.

If we now set $x_k=\sum_{l\neq k}c_lx_l$, the determinant of the whole matrix would be zero, so we found a linear form in the $x_i$ that divides the determinant.

A similar argument gives a linear form in the $y_i$ that divides the determinant.

Since the total degree in the $x_i$ is one and the total degree in the $y_i$ is one, this gives the determinant up to a constant factor and we see that the determinant is the product of two linear forms.